Maximum Number of Positve Zeros of a Polynomial
I saw the following claim:
If the terms of the polynomials are written in decreasing order of their powers, then the "number of sign changes of the coefficients" is the maximum possible number of positive zeros. In fact, the actual number of positive zeros may differ from this by an even number.
I was thinking using IVT, but I couldn't really formulate my ideas. And I have no clue on how to prove the second part of the claim.

This is known as "Descartes' rule of signs" if you want to look up proofs online

@PrincessEev Thank you so much! Didn't realize it's a well known result.
